# Find object value at index and store it in different array using swift

Tags: arrays, swift

Find object value at index and store it in a different array using swift.

Can someone tell me the most optimized way for the following code snippet

```
    var selectedIndex = [1,3,5]
    var allData : [Person] = []
    var ids: [Int] = []
    for (index, item) in allData.enumerated() {
        for id in selectedIndex {
            if id == index {
                ids.append(item.id)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: _"the most optimized way"_? `ids = [allData[1].id,allData[3].id,allData[5].id]`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Nothing wrong asking how to optimize his code. As it is he is unnecessarily iterating all elements in his collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure that all indices are valid you can simply map your selected indices:

```
let ids = selectedIndex.map { 
    allData[$0].id
}
```

If you want to make sure the selected index exists in allData:

```
let ids = selectedIndex.compactMap {
    allData.indices ~= $0 ? allData[$0].id : nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your indices are sorted, you can take just the portion of `allData` that you need, using `prefix`.

```swift
let ids =
  allData
  .prefix(selectedIndices.last.map { $0 + 1 } ?? 0)
  .enumerated()
  .compactMap {
    Optional($0)
      .filter { selectedIndices.contains($0.offset) }?
      .element.id
  }
```

```swift
public extension Optional {
  /// Transform `.some` into `.none`, if a condition fails.
  /// - Parameters:
  ///   - isSome: The condition that will result in `nil`, when evaluated to `false`.
  func filter(_ isSome: (Wrapped) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Self {
    try flatMap { try isSome($0) ? $0 : nil }
  }
}
```